# Criar senha aleatória diferente para cada registro em loop

Tags: php, loop

Tenho um *loop* que deveria inserir um senha aleatória para cada registro, e quando terminar o *loop* (ter criado a senha diferente para cada registro), listar os resultados visualizando a senha.

```
 <?php
ob_start();
session_start();

//conexão com banco
include ("conn.php");

//definição de variáveis
$tabela = "chatoperator";
$campos = "operatorid, vclogin, dtmlastvisited, istatus, vcpassword"; 
$quant = 10; //número de ações que será realizada de cada vez 
$sec = 10; //tempo entre o envio de um pacote e outro (em segundos) 
$ok = 0;
$inicio = 0;
$fim = $inicio + $quant; 
$acentos = "<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />";

//verifica se a senha confere com a da sessão
echo $acentos;

$sql = "select $campos from $tabela where istatus = 0 limit $inicio,$fim" or die (mysql_error($sql)); 
$query = mysql_query($sql,$conexao); 
$registros = mysql_num_rows($query); 

if($registros==0){
    mysql_query("update $tabela set istatus = 0" or die (mysql_error($conexao))); 
        echo("<font face=’tahoma’>todas as senhas foram alteradas!</font>"); 
    $ok = 1;
}else{
    while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $operatorid = $result[0]; //operatorid
        $vclogin = $result[1]; //vclogin
        $dtmlastvisited = $result[2]; //dtmlastvisited
        $istatus = $result[3]; //istatus
        $vcpassword = $result[4]; //vcpassword

        //gera senha aleatória
        function geraSenha(){
        //caracteres que serão usados na senha randomica
            $chars = 'abcdxyswzABCDZYWSZ0123456789';
            //ve o tamnha maximo que a senha pode ter
            $max = strlen($chars) - 1;
        //declara $senha
            $senha = null;

        //loop que gerará a senha de 8 caracteres
            for($i=0;$i < 8; $i++){
            $senha .= $chars{mt_rand(0,$max)};
    }
    return $senha;          
}
$senha_randomica   =  geraSenha();
$senha = md5($senha_randomica);

mysql_query("update $tabela set istatus = 1 AND vcpassword = '$senha_randomica' where    operatorid = $operatorid") or die (mysql_error($conexao));
    echo("
<table width='100%' border='1'>
    <tr>
        <th>Identificador do Usuário</th>
        <th>Login do Usuário</th>
        <th>Data do Último Acesso</th>
        <th>Status do Acesso</th>
        <th>Senha do Usuário</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
        <td> $operatorid </td>
        <td> $vclogin </td>
        <td> $dtmlastvisited </td>
        <td> $istatus </td>
        <td> $senha_randomica </td>
  </tr>
 </table>");
      }
   }
    mysql_free_result($query); 
    mysql_close($conexao);

    if(!$ok){
        echo("<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"" . $sec . "\">"); 
}
?>
```

Comment: Qual é sua dificuldade?

Comment: O script está gerando a MESMA senha para todos os registros, a idéia é que fosse gerada UMA senha diferente para cada registro. Obrigado pelo retorno @bigown

Comment: Sem indentação fica difícil entender o que está acontecendo. Se voc~e [edit]  a pergunta com melhor formatação do código, quem sabe até você mesmo encontre algum erro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema parece ser apenas que a função `geraSenha` está dentro do laço. Coloque ela antes de todo este código.

```
function geraSenha() {
    //caracteres que serão usados na senha randomica
    $chars = 'abcdxyswzABCDZYWSZ0123456789';
    //ve o tamnha maximo que a senha pode ter
    $max = strlen($chars) - 1;
    //declara $senha
    $senha = null;
    
    //loop que gerará a senha de 8 caracteres
    for ($i=0;$i < 8; $i++) {
        $senha .= $chars{mt_rand(0,$max)};
    }
    return $senha;          
}
$i = 0;
while ($i < 10) {
    echo geraSenha() . "\n";
    $i++;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/GCME6e). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/hxrzyfuz-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Algorithm/PasswordGen.php).

A pergunta fala claramente em problema para criar a senha e de fato sem a alteração acima eu testei e só gera uma. Agora nos comentários o problema parece ser outro. Há um erro também na gravação dos dados. Precisaria ser assim (se eu entendi a intenção).

```
mysql_query("update $tabela set istatus = 1, vcpassword = '$senha_randomica' where    operatorid = $operatorid") or die (mysql_error($conexao));
```

Então ficarias assim (não tem como eu testar um código que não segue o [MVCE](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

```
<?php
function geraSenha(){
    $chars = 'abcdxyswzABCDZYWSZ0123456789';
    $max = strlen($chars) - 1;
    $senha = "";
    for($i=0;$i < 8; $i++){
        $senha .= $chars{mt_rand(0,$max)};
    }
    return $senha;          
}

ob_start();
session_start();

//conexão com banco
include ("conn.php");

//definição de variáveis
$tabela = "chatoperator";
$campos = "operatorid, vclogin, dtmlastvisited, istatus, vcpassword"; 
$quant = 10; //número de ações que será realizada de cada vez 
$sec = 10; //tempo entre o envio de um pacote e outro (em segundos) 
$ok = 0;
$inicio = 0;
$fim = $inicio + $quant; 
$acentos = "<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />";

//verifica se a senha confere com a da sessão
echo $acentos;

$sql = "select $campos from $tabela where istatus = 0 limit $inicio,$fim" or die (mysql_error($sql)); 
$query = mysql_query($sql,$conexao); 
$registros = mysql_num_rows($query); 

if($registros==0){
    mysql_query("update $tabela set istatus = 0" or die (mysql_error($conexao))); 
        echo("<font face=’tahoma’>todas as senhas foram alteradas!</font>"); 
    $ok = 1;
}else{
    while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $operatorid = $result[0]; //operatorid
        $vclogin = $result[1]; //vclogin
        $dtmlastvisited = $result[2]; //dtmlastvisited
        $istatus = $result[3]; //istatus
        $vcpassword = $result[4]; //vcpassword

        $senha_randomica   =  geraSenha();
        $senha = md5($senha_randomica);

        mysql_query("update $tabela set istatus = 1, vcpassword = '$senha_randomica' where    operatorid = $operatorid") or die (mysql_error($conexao));
        echo("
<table width='100%' border='1'>
    <tr>
        <th>Identificador do Usuário</th>
        <th>Login do Usuário</th>
        <th>Data do Último Acesso</th>
        <th>Status do Acesso</th>
        <th>Senha do Usuário</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> $operatorid </td>
        <td> $vclogin </td>
        <td> $dtmlastvisited </td>
        <td> $istatus </td>
        <td> $senha_randomica </td>
    </tr>
</table>"
        );
    }
}
mysql_free_result($query); 
mysql_close($conexao);

if(!$ok){
    echo("<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"" . $sec . "\">"); 
}
?>
```

Comment: obrigado pelo retorno, porém tua solução gera 10 senhas (ou quantas eu parametrizar) mas ela não gera uma para cada registro dentro do loop, pode ajudar quanto a isto? Obrigado

Comment: A minha solução gera quantas você quiser. **basta tirar a função `geraSenha` de dentro do laço**. Eu não tenho como mostrar seu código funcionando por isto eu adaptei ele para mostrar que funciona. Eu vi que você não consegue indentar o código corretamente, então provavelmente se testou a minha solução com seu código deve ter mudado parte do código errado. Sem você entender claramente onde começa e termina uma coisa, fica difícil saber quais partes do código estão dando problema e quais precisam ser mexidas. A função deve ser movida para o início do código, mais nada.

Comment: Bom, indentar o código corretamente é só uma questão de visualização, isso não reflete o saber ou não de algo, mas tudo bem, não alterei nada do seu código, aliás é o mesmo que eu já havia testado anteriormente, porém, mesmo fora do laço/loop a senha é gerada, mas o problema é inserir uma em cada registro, e não a mesma em todos os registros. Se precisar de mais alguma informação para entender a MINHA dúvida para poder me ajudar, só informar, obrigado @bigown

Comment: Ñ é, esse é o problema, é uma questão de entendimento do que está fazendo. E é o que eu estou falando para você, se você entender o código, verá onde tem que alterar no seu. Eu não tenho como mostrar o seu funcionando porque ele depende do seu site. Então você tem que consertar o seu por conta própria, eu mostrei como faz para gerar uma para cada. Se você colocar um código que funcione e não dependa do seu site para funcionar, eu posso ajudar mais. Veja como deve fazer: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Eduardo, se a solução apresentada não resolveu seu caso, acho melhor você detalhar melhor a sua dificuldade, pois testando com um código simplificado aqui as senhas não repetem. E eu espero que você não entenda como crítica, mas eu demorei mais tempo para conseguir ler seu código do que para testar a solução do bigown. Até entendo que é seu direito usar um código todo bagunçado, mas já que você quer ajuda, podia indentar direito o código para facilitar pra quem está tendo boa vontade de ajudar. Inclusive, quanto mais organizado o programador, mais chance de achar ou nem sequer cometer erros.

Comment: A frase final do Bacco é o fundamental. Inclusive porque ela treina o cérebro para funcionar sempre procurando o correto. As pessoas ignoram o poder cognitivo que isto tem.

Comment: Eu não disse que senhas se repetem, eu disse que não geram uma para cada registro. Outra coisa é a questão de visualizar, meu código aqui é bem organizado, pois aprendi desta forma, mas como sempre busco aprender, obrigado pelos comentários, não os vejo de outra forma, porém neste site eu não fui muito feliz com a indentação. A minha dificuldade está bem detalhada na pergunta inicial, o problema não é a geração da senha, mas sim gravar uma para registro. Agradeço ao @bigown também pelas palavras.

Comment: @EduardoCorreia eu editei para colocar a parte do problema que você não havia citado antes em nenhum local.

Comment: Bom, eu não alterei o título e muito menos o texto da pergunta original, não sei porque esta afirmação que nos comentários de que não havia citado antes a dúvida ou que nos comentários seria outro problema amigo, me desculpe, se houve interpretação sua do texto não foi minha, pois mantenho desde o princípio que o problema não é a geração da senha, ou a quantidade dela, mas sim que não grava uma diferente para  cada registro. Quanto a correção query eu não havia visto mesmo, por isto que serve um serviço destes não é? Obrigado, vou testar.

Comment: Eu mostrei que o meu código gera uma diferente cada vez. Eu já lhe falei que se usar o meu código adaptado ao seu vai resolver o seu problema. Se quer que eu dê mostre mais adaptado ao seu faça o http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve q eu falei para você. Eu posso mostrar um exemplo funcionando mas tem que ser algo que funcione independente do seu site, que não precise de páginas e que não precise de um banco de dados. Eu faço a geração da senha como você precisa e gero toda informação necessária.

Comment: Bom, vamos ao fatos: o meu código ou o seu gera a senha aleatória. O meu código faz o loop mas insere no banco a mesma senha para todos, e não uma aleatória para cada registro. Você afirma que se adaptar o seu código ao meu vai funcionar, mas é justamente por não saber fazer isto que eu postei a pergunta aqui. A minha questão é se pode (qualquer pessoa) ajudar a fazer isso funcionar em definitivo, só isso.

Comment: O melhor que posso fazer é postar esta última edição, não tenho como testar mas é para funcionar. Note que o código indentado corretamente facilita a leitura e entendimento do mesmo. A solução está dada e aplicado ao seu caso. Como eu disse pode haver mais alguma coisa errada, mas o objetivo do site é dar soluções para a pergunta feita e não resolver todos os problemas do código que a pessoa posta. Agora, se não funcionar, você precisa ver o que precisa adaptar ou fazer uma nova pergunta com o problema novo específico que estiver tendo.

Comment: @bigown, ficou perfeito! Agradeço a atenção e a todos os que também se envolveram. O loop rodou, gravou uma senha diferente para cada registro e imprimiu a listagem até o final do laço. Espero que este script (e o conteúdo deste post) ajuda mais alguém. Este script é simples e gerou bastante discussão, acho isso bacana pois ha interatividade e espírito de ajuda. Eu sei que o nível deste script é basico, mas muito útil para uma determinada situação para mim. Obrigado